# Docker GitHub actions COPY failed: no source files were specified

Tags: java, docker, github, docker-compose, github-actions

I am trying to build a docker image on GitHub actions and here is the workflow for the same

```
jobs:
  deploy-dev:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build Application with Maven
      run: mvn clean install -DskipTests
    - name: Build image
      id: build-image
      env:
      run: |
          docker-compose build a-service
```

Here is the project structure

```
java-project/
├─ docker-compose.yml
├─ services/
│  ├─ a/
│  │  ├─ Dockerfile
│  │  ├─ pom.xml
│  ├─ b/
│  │  ├─ pom.xml
│  │  ├─ Dockerfile
├─ pom.xml
```

This is what the `docker-compose.yml` looks like for `service a`

```
services:
   a-service:
       container-name: a-service
       build:
          context: ./services/a
```

And finally here is the Dockerfile in the service a directory

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY src/main/xxxx/xxxx/xxx xxxx
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The deployment fails with the following message

```
Step 7/9 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

This works perfectly fine on local, but errors on GitHub actions. Any idea what could be going wrong? Note that there is no .dockerignore present in this project.

Comment: Env variable JAR_FILE is unset/empty.

Comment: i did a `RUN echo ${JAR_FILE}` and it shows `target/*.jar`

Comment: Sorry, can’t identify the actual cause, but - can you drop the env-variable in favor of fixed value „target/*.jar“?

Comment: I think the bigger issue could be the generation of the jar files itself. Do I need to specify the context or something for docker? I did not have to do anything of that sort for my local though. Will try what you suggested as well

Comment: `Step 4/6 : COPY target/*.jar app.jar`
`COPY failed: no source files were specified`

Comment: See? It isn‘t the ENV/ARG handling, the docker context is either not the expected directory or no jar is built.

Comment: any specific step needs to be added/modified in GitHub actions workflow?

Comment: Indeed it strongly seems related to the context:
https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/

Is your local maven config different such as that it deploys the jar directly into directory a? 

The actions file looks fine, you can omit the "with" in the checkout step. Probably modify the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.

Comment: @cwellm ive noticed that the jar files are built but are not being copied to target/. is there a specific step I need to Include after maven is triggered, for the jar files to be sent to target?